# Is there a workaround to the inflexible use of texture references in CUDA

Tags: textures, cuda

I have some textures which I want to read during some kernel launches. The documentation says that these have to be defined globally. The trouble is that I want to call the same kernel functions (which are quite complex) with different texture sources.

```
texture<unsigned char, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> g_tex_a;
texture<unsigned char, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> g_tex_b;

__global__ void gpu_kernel_1()
{
    // long complicated kernel
    foo = tex2D(g_tex_a, x,y);
}

__global__ void gpu_kernel_2()
{
    // long complicated kernel
    bar = tex2D(g_tex_a, x,y);
}

main()
{
    gpu_kernel_1<<<grid, block>>>();
    gpu_kernel_2<<<grid, block>>>();
}
```

Is it not possible to have a way of passing to the kernel which texture it should be reading from with tex2D, e.g. g_tex_a or g_tex_b? It seems that the compiler needs to know the texture reference at compile time. I want to be able to re-use the code of gpu_kernel_1 and gpu_kernel_2 to act on different textures.

I dont really understand the way that the texture reference object is utilized by host and device code. At the moment I have the horrid solution of replicating all the code for each kernel with the only change being that the tex2D function makes use of a different texture reference, e.g. gpu_kernel_1_with_tex_a(), gpu_kernel_1_with_tex_b().

Is there any other solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you pass an extra parameter to the kernel and use an `if/switch` condition? If all the threads goes the same path, wont have divergence. Regarding to your original question of passing a texture as parameter, I have no idea.

Comment: @pQB: Templating the parameter is an even better solution - dead code removal in the compiler will remove the code paths not used in a given instance of the kernel.

Comment: Thanks. I did not try templating it because I expected that the compiler would not allow templates for the kernel functions. However I admit I don't know that for certain.

Comment: Templates have been supported in CUDA from the beginning.  Template kernel functions are a very common and productive way to write generic kernel code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before a texture reference can be used, it must be mapped to memory, for instance with cudaBindTextureToArray(). It's in the mapping that you decide which data to operate on.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I had forgotten about the binding because its in a different part of the code which is just all set up once in some init function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the texture reference API, CUDA 5.0, now supports a texture object API. Instead of globally defining a texture reference, with this new API you can now locally define a texture object and pass it to a kernel as a function argument. Have a look at the CUDA programming guide (Section 3.2.10.1.1).

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-object-api